# Running Javascript as page opens

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I have a little problem, I want to run javascript as soon as page opens, however it does not work for me. On many forums and tutorials I tried they suggest using onload function in my case:

```
<body onload="loadPage()">
```

so my script is called loadPage, however it does not work... Instead of opening one of the pages(the links in if, else if statements) - a just have a blank page. Any help greatly appriciated!

```
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %> 
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.text.MessageFormat" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>

<%
    String place = request.getParameter("place");
%>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadPage() 
{
    if( <%=place%> == "birr")
    {
       window.open("http://localhost:82/IrishClimateData/Birr.jsp");
    }

    ...more else if statemens here...   

    else if( <%=place%> == "Shannonairport")
    {
       window.open("http://localhost:82/IrishClimateData/Shannon airport.jsp");
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadPage()">  
</body>
</html>
```

I played around with different options and did the following:

```
var placeName = "<%=place%>";
if( placeName == "birr")
```

I also had to add ; at the end of function. I thought apache tomcat would actually point it to me - as it usually does, but it did not... Thanks to all anyway!

Comment: "Does not work" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Comment: Please show your rendered HTML (without your server-side stuff)

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: check all the if...else statements. maybe there's a missing { or } . Try to use a switch

Comment: @LeeTaylor you mean the sourse code from browser? How do ipost it to you? Sorry I am new here...

Comment: @chepe263 Thanks, but there is no errors there, because it was copied from other web page which works fine.

Comment: @Evan nothing, no errors, no exeptions...

Comment: @AndreiIvanov What do the `<%` represent? I've actually never seen that syntax before - just curious :)

Comment: Run it in Chrome, hit F12. Do you have any errors, exceptions, *any* clues in the debugger?
This works, btw:
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadPage() 
{
  alert("yey");
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadPage()">  
</body>
</html>

Comment: @Evan JSP, for example you have jsp and JS in one page, for example the String called str is in JSP part of code, to use it in JS part of code (for example to copy) you do the following: var copy = "<%=str%>"; All the JSP code is in these as well <% code %>

Answer (score 2):

After removing your server side code and simplifying your loadPage function, it looks like it will run fine. Here is a live example: http://jsbin.com/ozetah/2/?place=birr

The live example code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadPage() {
  // code to replicate server side capture of GET parameter
  var place = /place=(.*?)(?:$|&)/.exec(document.location.search);
  if( place.length >1 ) { place = place[1]; }


  if( place == "birr") {
    window.open("http://localhost:82/IrishClimateData/Birr.jsp");
  } else if( place == "Shannonairport") {
    window.open("http://localhost:82/IrishClimateData/Shannon airport.jsp");
  } else {
    alert('place param of "'+place+'" doesn\'t match');
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadPage()">  
</body>
</html>
```

Since all of this works and you are not seeing any errors in your code, I would check the html output to make sure your server side code is outputting what you would expect. You can take out all of the server side code and start adding pieces back in to see what breaks it.

Comment: Thank for your reply, I played around with different options and did the following: var placeName = "<%=place%>"; and in my if else statements: if( placeName == "belmullet"), I also had to add ; at the end of function. I thought apache tomcat would actually point it to me - as it usually does... Thanks anyway!